# Saving textbox content as image file

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform, save-as

While I found a way of saving the content of a textbox located in a worksheet as an image file (png, bmp, jpeg), I am not able to achieve the same thing for a textbox located in a userform.
The attached code returns a blank picture.
Could somebody point me in the right direction, please?

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' save textbox content as image file
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim ActiveShape As Shape
    
    TextBox1.Text = "12345"
    ' select the TextBox
    TextBox1.SetFocus
    ' Copy selection
    Selection.Copy
    '
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    ' paste selection into a picture shape
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste(link:=False).Select
    Set ActiveShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveWindow.Selection.Name)
    ' Create temporary chart object (same size as shape)
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
    Width:=ActiveShape.Width, Top:=ActiveCell.Top, Height:=ActiveShape.Height)
    ' Format temporary chart to have a transparent background
    cht.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    cht.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    ' Copy/Paste Shape inside temporary chart
    ActiveShape.Copy
    cht.Activate
    ActiveChart.Paste
    'Save chart to User's Desktop as image file
     cht.Chart.Export Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & "TextBoxImage" & ".bmp"
    'Delete temporary Chart
    cht.Delete
    ActiveShape.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that user form text box does not have the necessary `CopyPicture` property. Even for a sheet ActiveX text box, `Copy` does not return the object picture...

So, you can accomplish what you wan, only using a trick: Create such a text box clone on the sheet and use it to export the picture:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim ob As OLEObject, sh As Worksheet, tb As msforms.TextBox, ch As ChartObject, pictName As String

  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  pictName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\TextBoxImage.jpg"
    Set ob = sh.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1", link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, left:=383.4, top:=29.4, width:=Me.TextBox1.width, height:=Me.TextBox1.height)
    Set tb = ob.Object
    DoEvents
    With tb
        .Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
        .BackColor = Me.TextBox1.BackColor
        .ForeColor = Me.TextBox1.ForeColor
        .Font = Me.TextBox1.Font
        .Font.Size = Me.TextBox1.Font.Size
    End With
    DoEvents
    Set ch = sh.ChartObjects.Add(left:=1, _
       top:=1, width:=tb.width, height:=tb.height)

       tb.CopyPicture: ch.Activate: ActiveChart.Paste
       ch.Chart.Export pictName, "JPEG"
      ch.Delete
      ob.Delete
End Sub
```

If necessary, some other text box properties can be copied in the same way (Bold, Italics etc.).

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @F Home Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?